# Add non native cordova plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

How do I add non native cordova plugin? I have to add https://github.com/heigeo/cordova-plugin-tensorflow plugin. How to add and where to make necessary changes? If you have any such code please include here in answer. Thanks already.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in the readme of the link you have shared : 
Execute - "cordova plugin add https://github.com/heigeo/cordova-plugin-tensorflow"